In Leviticus 14:34 could 'natatiy' mean "allow"?
Leviticus 14:34 NASB95:

When you enter the land of Canaan, which I give you for a possession, and I put a mark of leprosy on a house in the land of your possession,

"I put," is Hebrew 'natatiy' (Strong's H5414). Could this be translated as merely "allow," in this verse and linguistic context instead of the active, "put"?
I have checked several commentaries, and many of them do suggest that "allow" could be the intended meaning, but none of them say that should be the translation of the word. They all suggest this by saying that in the Semitic culture they would often attribute to God actions that He merely allowed. Perhaps these commentators do not suggest "allow" as a translation because there is something in the grammar or sentence structure that forces a more active verb?

Welcome to SE-BH. Please see the Tour and the Help as to the purpose and the functioning of the site. Please also see the archive of 15,000 question/answer contributions as to how these policies play out in practice.

נָתַן nathan See Biblehub Interlinear  is variously translated 'put' 'give' 'yield' 'deliver' 'set' lay' 'make' and 'establish' See Strong H5414. It is clearly a word with a broad spectrum of meaning. But 'allow' has a different connotation to it than the above list of meanings. I suggest a similar Greek word might be tithemi, for comparison.  See Strong G5087.

Interestingly, the same verb נָתַן (nathan) occurs twice in different forms in Lev 14:34 as follows:

נֹתֵ֥ן (translated "give" in the OP's version) is a Qal participle
וְנָתַתִּי֙ (translated "and put" in the OP's version) is Qal conjunctive perfect

In the rest of the OT, it occurs over 2000 times, ie, a very common verb with a range of meanings but basically means, "give, put, set".  See https://biblehub.com/hebrew/5414.htm for all the details.
I notice that within the spectrum of meaning of this word, "allow, let" appears sometimes in places such as: Gen 20:6, 2 Chron 20:10, Deut 18:14, Ps 132:4, Prov 6:4, Lam 2:18, Isa 62:6.  Such meanings involve the accusative with an infinitive
However, in Lev 14:34 does not involve such grammatical constructions.  But that does not prevent the meaning of "allow" because in Hebrew thinking, God is often thought of as the cause of that which He does not prevent.  See appendix below.
APPENDIX - Divine Passive

Lam 3:38 - Do not both adversity and good come from the mouth of the
Most High?
Isa 45:7 - I form the light and create the darkness; I bring
prosperity and create calamity. I, the LORD, do all these things

The idea of the Divine Passive is one that is not explicit in the Bible but was created to explain the available, apparently contradictory, facts.  Here are some examples:

2 Sam 24:1 vs 1 Chron 21:1 – Who tempted King David to have a census? God or Satan?  Both are correct because to the Hebrew mind, God is omniscient and omnipotent and thus events only occur if He allows.  James 1:13 explicitly states that God tempts no one.
Job 2:3 - God says that Satan "incited" God to ruin Job, even though it was Satan that was the direct cause of Job's ruin
1 Sam 16:14, 16, 18:10, 19:9 – God sent an evil (literally, unclean) spirit on Saul?  God does not have an evil spirit to send!  Again, the omnipotent God is deemed responsible for that which He does not prevent.
Judges 9:23 has an identical idea of an evil spirit from God.
1 Kings 2:22, 23, 2 Chron 18:21, 22 all have a “lying spirit” from the LORD.
Ex 9:12, 10:1, 20, 27, 11:10, 14:8 – God causes Pharaoh to harden his heart???  Clearly not!  Compare Ex 8:15, 32, 9:34 where Pharaoh hardens his own heart.
Compare Rev 17:1 where God judges the great prostitute, with, Rev 17:16, 17 where the great prostitute becomes a victim of her own wicked ways.
In Eze 14:9 says, “I the LORD have enticed/deceived that prophet”; whereas James 1:13 says that God does not tempt anyone.
Eze 20 – Judah makes some bad choices and rejects God’s laws and so God gives them other statutes and laws including child sacrifice (V25, 26).  In fact, this is what Judah has chosen.

This principle can be readily extrapolated to other many (not all) other passages where the passive voice is used; eg, the beatitudes of Matt 5, Rom 3:28, 1 Cor 7:23, Gal 5:13, Eph 2:5, Matt 9:2, 1 Peter 1:18.
This same idea is expressed another way in some places where God allows sin and evil to reap its own consequences and cause its own downfall.

Job 5:13 - He catches the wise in their own craftiness, and the schemes of the wily are brought to a quick end.
Ps 5:10 - Declare them guilty, O God; let them fall by their own devices. Drive them out for their many transgressions, for they have rebelled against You.
Ps 7:15 - He has dug a hole and hollowed it out; he has fallen into a pit of his own making.
Ps 9:16 - The LORD is known by the justice He brings; the wicked are ensnared by the work of their hands.
Ps 37:14, 15 - The wicked have drawn the sword and bent the bow to bring down the poor and needy, to slay those whose ways are upright. But their swords will pierce their own hearts, and their bows will be broken
Ps 69:22 - Let their own table before them become a snare; and when they are at peace, let it become a trap.
Ps 141:10 - Let the wicked fall into their own nets, while I pass by in safety.
Prov 5:22 - The iniquities of a wicked man entrap him; the cords of his sin entangle him.
Prov 11:6 - The righteousness of the upright delivers them, but the faithless are trapped by their own desires.
Prov 12:13 - An evil man is trapped by his rebellious speech, but a righteous man escapes from trouble.
Prov 28:10 - He who leads the upright along the path of evil will fall into his own pit, but the blameless will inherit what is good.
Isa 3:11 - Woe to the wicked; disaster is upon them! For they will be repaid with what their hands have done
Hos 11:6 – A sword will flash through their cities; it will destroy the bars of their gates and consume them in their own plans.


Thank you for the detailed look at this, it is helpful. So, perhaps in a thought for thought translation it may work, but not a word for word translation.

@CalebJones - word-for-word translations are often misleading as they suggest that words have fixed meaning which is patently false.  Hebrew words all have a range of meanings and are generally used flexibly.

For Leviticus 14:34, the Jewish scholars tasked with translating the Tanakh from Hebrew to Greek under the auspices of the Sanhedrin, chose the Greek word, δίδωμι (SG1325), which means "to give." You can compare all nine instances of δίδωμι in the New Testament here:
https://biblehub.com/greek/dido_mi_1325.htm
Notice that the semantic range of this word does not include anything close to "allow."
Hope this helps.

Thank you! I do find the Septuagint as a very helpful resource for understanding how the 2nd temple Jews would have understood a verse.
